# QueryOver by alias with NHibernate is using property name not column mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm having trouble specifying the QueryOver order by clause with an object whose property name does not match the column name.

Here is the object: -

```
public class ObjectInstance
{ 
    public ObjectInstance()
    {
        IsActive = true;
    }

    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And the hibernate fluent mapping: -

```
public class ObjectInstanceMap : ClassMap<ObjectInstance>
{
    public ObjectInstanceMap()
    {
        Table("ObjectInstances");
        Id(obj => obj.ObjectInstanceId).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
        Map(x => x.IsActive, "ObjectInstanceIsActive");
    }
}
```

As you can see the column in the database is called ObjectInstanceIsActive, but is being mapped to the IsActive property on the ObjectInstance object. Trying to get an IList out with a QueryOver as follows: -

```
IList<ObjectInstance> result = this.Session.QueryOver<ObjectInstance>(() => objectInstance)
    .UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new Order("ObjectInstanceIsActive", true))
    .List<ObjectInstance>();
```

Throws an error stating that the ObjectInstance object doesn't have an ObjectInstanceIsActive property, which is correct, it doesn't.

If I change the criteria to be: -

```
IList<ObjectInstance> result = this.Session.QueryOver<ObjectInstance>(() => objectInstance)
    .UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new Order("IsActive", true))
    .List<ObjectInstance>();
```

Then Hibernate generates an SQL query successfully, but its looking for a column called IsActive which doesn't exists and errors.

I've also tried adding the below projections (separately) but that didn't help.

```
.Select(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Property("IsActive"), "ObjectInstanceIsActive"))
.Select(Projections.ProjectionList().Add(Projections.Property("IsActive"),   "ObjectInstanceIsActive"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had over-simplified my example. ObjectInstance was a base class and as a stand alone everything works perfectly as MichaC and Radim pointed out. In my particular scenario I had a child class inheriting from it which was re-mapping the IsActive column under a different alias that went unnoticed.

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<ObjectInstance> result = this.Session.QueryOver<ObjectInstance>(() => objectInstance)
  .UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new Order("IsActive", true))
  .List<ObjectInstance>();
```

Works actually fine for me, creates the following statement as expected:

```
SELECT this_.ObjectInstanceId as ObjectIn1_19_0_, this_.ObjectInstanceIsActive as 
ObjectIn2_19_0_ FROM ObjectInstances this_ 
ORDER BY this_.ObjectInstanceIsActive asc
```

Answer (score 1):

The fluent mapping and the query itself are looking well. Check again what is the SQL generated in case of using `new Order("IsActive", true)`...this is suspicious.

By the way, more fluent (and type safe) syntax is:

```
var result = Session
    .QueryOver<ObjectInstance>(() => objectInstance)
    .OrderBy(() => objectInstance.IsActive)
      .Asc
    .List<ObjectInstance>();
```